# Java 8 Lambda - filter two ArrayList

Tags: java, list, lambda, filter, java-8

I have two lists. The first one is an ID list of regions, the second one is a node list which has nested region objects.

Structure of my `nodeList`:

```
....{
 "id": 6412,
 "name": "303000201",
 "description": "desc",
 "organization": {
    "id": 41065,
    "name": "adad",
    "address": null
 },
 "region": {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "Quba rayonu",
    "code": "303"
 },
 "nodeType": {
    "id": "WELL",
    "name": "Quyu",
    "description": null
 },
 "location": {
    "id": 6412,
    "latitude": 41.36735554,
    "longitude": 48.5041245554
 }} ......
```

And region list:

```
{
  "regions": ["56", "44"]
}
```

I must filter my `nodeList` for region ID. I do it the old way but I want to do it with lambda expressions. How can I do it?

I googled, tried, but it doesn't work :/

```
result= nodeList.stream()
                .filter(n -> regionIDList.equals(n.getRegion().getId().toString()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `regionIDList` is a `List`, use [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) instead of `equals`:

```
result = nodeList.stream()
                 .filter(n -> regionIDList.contains(n.getRegion().getId().toString()))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you once again ;) It works . But still have a little problem . It return result correctly but there are many null objects  inside result list after 1500th object :/ Is it make left join ?)) I don;t understand

Comment: I need to check if Node (n)  is not null

Comment: nodeListFilteredForRegion = nodeList.stream().filter(n -> Objects.nonNull(n))
     .filter(n -> regionIDList.contains(n.getRegion().getId().toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());    I have solved